# How to mock a parameter from a decorator no python

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to simulate the value to soup of a decorator parameter in the unit test.

Code:

```
# decorator 
def get_data(soup, tag, tipo):
    def valid(func):
        def inner(*args):
                return soup.findAll(tag, {"class": tipo})
        return inner
    return valid


@get_data(soup, "h2", "product__title")
def gerar_nomes():
    return value
```

Unit Test:

```
self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.code, 'html.parser')
self.codnomes = desa.generate_names(self.soup)

 def test_generate_names(self):
        self.assertEqual('<h2 class="product__title">p1</h2>', str(self.codnomes[0]))
        self.assertEqual('<h2 class="product__title">p2</h2>', str(self.codnomes[1]))
```

Comment: You can't, the decorator is resolved when you import the module. Perhaps that's not the most testable implementation

Comment: In fact, why is it even a decorator? It ignores the function it wraps.